# How to configure DNSMasq to allow wildcards for dns entries from DHCP?

Tags: dhcp, pfsense, dnsmasq, bsd

I'm using PFSenses 2.0 in our development environment.

I'm depending on the DNS Forwarder to add DNS entries for new DHCP leases. This is working well, though I need to add support for wildcards to these DNS entries.

I know you can use address=/com/192.168.2.1 to set a wildcard, but I don't know the IP address of the machine yet.

An example scenario:

A new vm starts and issues a DHCP Request with hostname "stage01" on the domain example.com
Once it is provided an IP, the DNS correctly resolves stage01.example.com to that domain. Though I also require *.stage01.example.com to resolve to this address.

Since I do not know the MAC or IP address ahead of time, is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of would be to simply CNAME `*.stage01.example.com` to point at `stage01.example.com` in your DNS server.

The dynamic update will change `stage01.example.com`'s address, and the wildcard CNAME will take care of the rest for you.